# SP's in my SQL Azure Db is throwing word breaking errors

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am getting the below error frequently when executing my SP's in SQL Azure DB its not consistent and I am using MS SQL Server 2014 Express. Please advise me the reason for this issue and how to resolve it.

Msg
30053, Level 16, State 102, Line 4

An error has occurred during the full-text query. Common causes include: word-breaking errors or timeout, FDHOST Permissions/ACL issues, service account missing privileges, malfunctioning IFilters, communication channel issues with FDHost and sqlservr.exe, etc

Thanks,

Arunraj.

Answer (score 0):

The word breaker may be trying to verify signature, and unable to reach the service

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('VerifySignature');
GO
-- if 1, then turn off verify_signature
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0;
GO
```

[Go with msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms142509.aspx)

or You can check this in  [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on the platform side. The fix has been identified and it is in the process of being rolled out. Meanwhile we can mitigate this manually, but we need details with server/database names - you can email them to mihaelab at Microsoft dot com.

Thanks,

Mihaela